# Update an Access field when YES/NO field changes

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

I have an Access database 2016 and within a table in the database there is a yes/no field (checkbox), when a technitian clicks the checkbox, i want the datefield to update. I.E when he completes a task, check this box and the time is logged, it needs to be within the table, NOT a form. How do you do this with the checkboxes right in the table, NOT in a form.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are database triggers, since access does not have them they introduced data macros which you can create for update / delete / etc.

See this:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?CorrelationId=e1f083ce-b083-439a-86fb-4f56439ebb63&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010378170

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are completing the CompletedBy Field and the checkbox on a form or web page, why not complete the CompletedDate at the same time in a hidden control / update statement and not bother with the checkbox.

It's redundant really as if it has a completed date by definition it's completed.

Comment: The completed by field was a test for something else that is not used anymore. And read the question... NO form, i dont even know why you mention web page, where did you read that? This is an access database with checkboxes for every record.

Comment: That sounds as if the users are editing the table directly, which is very bad practice. If that is how the database is being used then data macro's are the only way.
But data entry or update should be done in a form, never directly in a table.

Comment: I completely understand that. Please, for the purposes of what im doing, this is completely acceptable. Would you be able to post an answer with the data macros? I havent been able to set one up correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used them as 99% of my development work is with SQL Server with Access as a front end. 
Having had a quick look though, you would open the table and create it from the table tools . You want an after update event based on the checkbox contents.
On a form based on the table this would be 2 minutes work.